# AndEngine - Destroy body from scene class?

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

I have a class that extends scene, which controls the game. In my ContactListener I have:

```
if (x1.getBody().getUserData().equals("wall")
                        && x2.getBody().getUserData().equals("arrow")) {
                    System.out.println("arrow is x2");
                }
```

When the arrow, x2 collides with wall, x1, I want the arrow body to be destroyed. They collide, but of course I can't destroy it from ContactListener. Since this class extends scene how could I either get an update or run method in it (all the other posts I've seen on this had classes which have extended BaseGameActivity), or destroy the x2 body otherwise?

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution for you.

When you create a scene pass a BaseGameActivity reference to it. Like in the following

```
new GameScene(MainActivity mainAcivity);
```

Then after remove box2d object you have to use this reference.

```
mainActivity.runOnUpdateThread(){  
    public void run(){
          mPhysicsWorld.destroyBody(arrowBody);
    }
}
```